# How to add glyphicon to xPage bootstrap dropdownbutton?

Tags: css, xpages

Here is my dropdownbutton:

```
<xp_1:dropDownButton id="dropDownButton1">
    <xp_1:this.treeNodes>
        <xp_1:basicContainerNode styleClass="btn-primary" label="Tools">
            <xp_1:this.children>
                <xp_1:basicLeafNode label="Edit">
                </xp_1:basicLeafNode>
                <xp_1:basicLeafNode label="New">
                </xp_1:basicLeafNode>
                <xp_1:basicLeafNode label="Home">
                </xp_1:basicLeafNode>
            </xp_1:this.children>
        </xp_1:basicContainerNode>
    </xp_1:this.treeNodes>
</xp_1:dropDownButton>
```

How to add glyphicon to the main dropdown button?
Adding a span somewhere inside just doesn't work like for core button:

```
<xp:button id="button2" styleClass="btn btn-success" value="Save" title="Save">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: I suspect the XPages rendering class for the button control is ignoring or overwriting anything you put in the `<xp:button>` tag. You may want to consider a different approach such has using plain html markup for the button and attaching an onclick event to it that triggers `$("buttonselector").trigger('click')` a hidden button `<xp:button style="display:none">`. The hidden button would contain your server side event (SSJS code).

Answer (score 0):

Once you add code in your button, i.e. an eventHandler, you can add the icon there.  Here is a button I have that includes a Font Awesome icon, but Glyphicons work the same way.  Once you create the button and actions, go into the source code and add the icon as below:

```
<xp:button
    value="Submit"
    id="btnSave"
    styleClass="btn btn-primary"
>
    <i
        class="fa fa-check"
        aria-hidden="true"
    ></i>
    &#160;<xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete"
    >
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:saveDocument
                    var="currentDocument"
                ></xp:saveDocument>
                <xp:openPage
                    name="#{sessionScope.lastPageName}"
                ></xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

**UPDATE**

I did some tests, and while you can't add the icon the way we both want to, you can use CSS.  I used a page with one dropdown button, and added CSS :before to add the icon within the button:

```
button::before {
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: "\e172";
}
```

You may have to play with the CSS a little but hopefully, this can help.

Comment: the question is about Dropdown button. See code above. You right it's easy to add glyph icon to the button itself but how to add it to a dropdown one?